# Intercept fake urls for runtime mapping in .Net Core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, routes, url-routing, blazor

I would like to have some urls in my application that are created at runtime, stored in a database, and not mapped to physical pages. Something like myapp.com/User-defined-Url.

The user will enter the User-defined-Url and the string message they want to show. All of these pages will use the same controller to show the message.

How do I map all unknown URLs to a single controller?

Here is what I have so far:

_Host.cshtml:

```
 ...
 <body>
  <app>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
  </app>
 </body>
```

Main.razor:

```
 <Myintercept></Myintercept>
```

app.razor:

```
 <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    You must log in to view this page.
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    Redirecting...
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
```

Myintercept.cs

```
    ...
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {  //this runs and gets the text to show }
```

So the Myintercept component runs and builds what I want to show, but the NotFound text in app.razor gets shown instead.

Comment: Do you just want to show a basic string, with no HTML/view/whatever?

Comment: No, I am simplifying it a bit. There are actually multiple options in the razor page.

Comment: Then you could create a catch-all route https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-template-reference

Comment: does that work in blazor? I am also using .net 4.8.